# Why products to consume are cancelled in manufacturing order Odoo v9 using xml-rpc?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm creating the manufacturing order

```
# Create production 
new_manufacturing = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
            'mrp.production', 'create',
            [{'product_id':155,'product_uom':1, 'bom_id':54, 'product_qty': 1.0}],)

# confirm production
models.exec_workflow(db, uid, password, "mrp.production", 'button_confirm', new_manufacturing)
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'mrp.production', 'force_production', [new_manufacturing])

#context consume product wizard.
context={'active_id': new_manufacturing, 'active_ids': [new_manufacturing], "active_model": "mrp.production"}

produce_id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
'mrp.product.produce', 'create',
[{}, context])

models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'mrp.product.produce', 'do_produce', [[produce_id], context])
```

but then the product to consume(bill of material) are canceled 
[printscreen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xnrL.png)
[printscreen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXwM2.png)

Comment: I took a look at what the mrp workflows. There is a fair amount going on there and unfortunately I cant spend more time on it at the moment. What I think may be going on is that when you run the `force_production` function it runs some validation functions such as `trg_validate()`. I would suggest placing some logging and printing on both the odoo code as well as on the rpc script.

Comment: Follow each stage and print the the value of the state field every step of the way. Eventually you will find the point at which the state is written to cancel and if you are logging on both sides (odoo / script) you will be able to find the point in the code that is failing. My guess is that there is some field / step which you have missed and once you set that field or execute that step it should work.

Comment: If you are logging on both sides you will eventually narrow it to one line of code and find the issue. The `test_ready()` and `trg_validate()` functions look like they could be the cause. They are both components of the `force_production()` method. If I get more time I will take another look.

Comment: i think force production works well, but thre problems are rather in `produce_id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
'mrp.product.produce', 'create',
[{}, context]) ` when i read what is in produce_id (instance of 'mrp.product.produce') consume_lines  is empty. I think i need to create some consume lines pointing to produce_id